# afterEvaluate not working after updating android gradle plugin to 4.1.0

Tags: android, gradle

Hello we use `afterEvaluate` in our root `build.gradle` to set some `BuildConfig` values and upload archives, but after updating gradle plugin from

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1
```

to

```
com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0
```

It seems `afterEvaluate` is not being triggered at all.

Any idea how to solve this issue?

`build.gradle` looks like this

```
subprojects{
...
 android{
 ...
    afterEvaluate { project ->
        buildTypes.each { buildType ->
            final String suffix = buildType.name == 'release' ? '' : ".${buildType.name}"

            project.libraryApplicationIds.each { String constant, String libAppId ->
                buildType.buildConfigField "String", constant, "\"$libAppId$suffix\""
                buildType.manifestPlaceholders[constant] = "$libAppId$suffix"
            }
        }
    }
 ...
 }
...
}
```

Comment: Add more parts of your `build.gradle` file, especially the parts inside the `afterEvaluate` closure.

Comment: @LukasKörfer added

Answer (score 3):

Looks like I have faced the same issue, but found it in our Gradle plugins which suppose to inject build config fields in app variants.

I managed to reproduce this on clean project with such simple plugin which emulates what we do in our plugin.

```
class MyPlugin: Plugin<Project> {

    override fun apply(project: Project) {
        project.afterEvaluate {
            val androidExtension = project.extensions.getByType(AppExtension::class.java)
            androidExtension.applicationVariants.forEach {
                System.out.println("Adding build config for ${it.name}")
                it.buildConfigField("String", "TEST_CONFIG", "\"TEST\"")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Gradle version in both cases is `6.5`

So I just change AGP version from `4.0.2` to `4.1.0`. In the former case
(ver. 4.0.2) it works fine and `TEST_CONFIG` field is added to `BuildConfig`, in the latter field is not added to `BuildConfig`

What I noticed is that build logs are different in both cases when I run `./gradlew :app:generateDebugBuildConfig`

For old plugin version when everything works output is:

```
> Configure project :app

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
Adding build config for debug
Adding build config for release
```

For new plugin version when it does not work:

```
> Configure project :app

> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
Adding build config for debug
Adding build config for release
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig
```

So it looks like there are some internal changes in the plugin which cause this reordering, but unfortunately I have not found the fix yet

UPDATE: I have found that this got broken in version `4.1.0-alpha08`

UPDATE: [Sample project on Github](https://github.com/silin/android-gradle-plugin-issue)

UPDATE: Reported to Google, waiting for response - [Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/171898346)

Comment: For now I've rewritten the code to not set build config fields inside afterEvaluate. Setting them normally somewhere else in the gradle build script still works for me